# How to create a data_by_subject function in Python

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

Please help me. I don't know what I'm doing and my professor wants this written in a way that is super hard to look up since it's not the most efficient way to write code. I can't move on to the next part of the assignment until I write this function.

These are the instructions for the function I need to write:

App.data_by_subject function

For this function assume that the complete data set (as a list of dictionaries) is stored in a variable named ALL_DATA.  For testing purposes you can read the contents of a CSV file using the readCSV function and assign the returned value to that variable.

To avoid problems when submitting to AutoLab:

1. do NOT add parameters for data_by_subject
2. do NOT name the parameter of this function ALL_DATA
3. do NOT assign a value to ALL_DATA inside this function
4. you may assign a value to ALL_DATA outside of any function, so that you can call these functions for your own testing - the autograding code will overwrite any value you assign to the variable before running its tests.

This function must return the data needed by Plotly to display a donut chart, as described above.  The argument to this function will be a dictionary in this format:

```
{ "year_start": integer, "year_end": integer }
```

For example, here are some possible dictionaries:

```
{ "year_start": 2004, "year_end": 2012 }
{ "year_start": 2018, "year_end": 2018 }
```

For each year in the range (remembering that both endpoints are included) prepare a dictionary in the following general format:

```
{
  "values": [3, 17, 80],
  "labels": ['Dept A', 'Dept B', 'Dept C'],
  "domain": {"column": 0},
  "name": '2004',
  "hole": .4,
  "type": 'pie'
}
```

The values are determined for each department by counting how many service requests there were for that department in the given year, and then dividing by the total number of service requests in the year.  Express this percentage as an integer between 0 and 100.

Compute the percentage long these lines:

```
int( 100*round(deptCount/totalCount, 2))
```

Use the functions defined in HW4, as well as the filterYear function, to collect together the relevant data items to determine these counts (e.g. filterYear will let you grab the service requests for a given year, and keepOnly will let you pull out the service requests for a specific department).

So that the same departments are represented in every dictionary, use the App.departments function to get a list of departments for the entire data set.

The value returned will be a list of these dictionaries, one per year in range, where the 'name' key is paired with the year.  For example:

```
[
{
  "values": [3, 17, 80],
  "labels": ['Dept A', 'Dept B', 'Dept C'],
  "domain": {"column": 0},
  "name": '2004',
  "hole": .4,
  "type": 'pie'
}
,
{
  "values": [5, 35, 60],
  "labels": ['Dept A', 'Dept B', 'Dept C'],
  "domain": {"column": 1},
  "name": '2005',
  "hole": .4,
  "type": 'pie'
}
]
```

This is the code I have already written that can be used to build this function:

```
def departments(list_of_dictionaries):
  departmentNames = []
  for n in list_of_dictionaries:
    value=(n["SUBJECT"])
    if value not in departmentNames:
      departmentNames.append(value)
      departmentNames.sort()
  return departmentNames

def open_year(dictionary):
  open_date = dictionary["OPEN DATE"]
  year = open_date[6:10]
  return year

def filterYear(list_of_dictionaries,low,high):
  List = []
  for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    if int(low) <= int(open_year(d)) < int(high):
      List = List + [d] 
  return List


def readCSV(filename):
    listOfRecords = []
    with open(filename, newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = next(reader)
        print(headers)
        for record in reader:
            aDict = {}
            for i in range(len(headers)):
                aDict[headers[i]] = record[i]
            listOfRecords.append(aDict)
    return listOfRecords

ALL_DATA = readCSV("311_Service_Requests_Abbreviated.csv")


def keepOnly(list_of_dictionaries,key,value):
  acc = []
  for i in list_of_dictionaries:
      if key in i and i[key] == value:
        acc.append(i)
  return acc
```

this is the CSV file I am using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B8VcNxhvYddzejdP3jjk31-OqZCyNfan/view?usp=sharing
)

TL;DR
I need to use the functions I wrote previously to extract department names and how many times they were called per year from the CSV so that it can be used to plot data in the donut chart later.

Some lines from CSV:

```
1000522614  04/23/2016 11:37:00 AM  04/26/2016 5:52:00 AM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Sanitation  Garbage Missed Pick Up (Req_Serv)   Street      BRIDGEMAN       Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000522658  04/25/2016 8:56:00 AM   04/29/2016 3:21:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Engineering - Street Repairs    Pot Hole (Req_Serv) Street      May St      Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000522679  04/25/2016 9:19:00 AM   04/26/2016 8:34:00 AM   Closed  Dept of Parking Parking Violations Bureau   PVB Single Meter (Req_Serv) Street      Delaware Ave        Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000522881  04/25/2016 1:39:00 PM   04/26/2016 4:52:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Streets Excess Trash (Req_Serv) Street      Meadow Rd       Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000522925  04/25/2016 2:28:00 PM   04/25/2016 2:37:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Animal Shelter  Animals (Req_Serv)  Property    26  CITY LINE       Buffalo NY      90.75-5-21                                  UNKNOWN     
1000522980  04/25/2016 5:30:00 PM   04/26/2016 4:52:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Streets Excess Trash (Req_Serv) Street      SEABROOK        Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000522999  04/26/2016 8:35:00 AM   04/26/2016 4:51:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Streets Excess Trash (Req_Serv) Street      SEABROOK        Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000523084  04/26/2016 11:01:00 AM  04/26/2016 3:28:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Parking Parking Violations Bureau   PVB Single Meter (Req_Serv) Street      HERTEL      Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN     
1000523331  04/27/2016 10:57:00 AM  05/03/2016 7:00:00 AM   Closed  Dept of Public Works    Forestry    Stump Removal (Req_Serv)    Property    10  RACHEL VINCENT WAY      Buffalo NY      78.49-7-2                                   UNKNOWN     
1000523634  04/28/2016 10:37:00 AM  04/28/2016 4:02:00 PM   Closed  Dept of Parking Parking Violations Bureau   PVB Single Meter (Req_Serv) Street      VIRGINIA ST     Buffalo NY                                          UNKNOWN
```

What gets returned needs to look like this:

```
  {
      "values": [3, 7],
      "labels": ['Dept of Parking', 'Dept of Public Works'],
      "domain": {"column": 0},
      "name": '2016',
      "hole": .4,
      "type": 'pie'
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to simplify your problem statement by additionally posting a few (e.g. ten) lines of your csv file, and the expected output for e.g., `data_by_subject({"year_start": 2010, "year_end": 2012})`.  You will more likely get answers if you try to simplify as much as possible.

Comment: So the output you posted could have been obtained with `data_by_subject({"year_start": 2015, "year_end": 2016})`, is that it?

Comment: Yes but I think I figured it out. Thank you for taking a look.